# Why is the Baryon Acoustic Oscillations (BAO) calculated like this?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, bao

In the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Baryon_acoustic_oscillations), it says that, when calculating the Baryon Acoustic Oscillations (sound horizon), we measure $150\text{ Mpc}$, saying that the sound horizon is the "Physical Length of sound horizon at today". Then it says that, when correcting for expansion, the physical length must be calculated by:

x(physical length of sound horizon) = a(scale factor) * X(comoving distance of sound horizon at drag epoch) 150Mpc(today)=1*150

(I just copied Wikipedia's text, that's why I don't format it). I have two doubts. The first one is, which os those distances is the one you measure, the $150\text{ Mpc}$?

The second one, why is the comoving distance of sound horizon set to $1$? I see it multiplies three terms. Is that right? So if I were to calculate the angular distance in the sky those oscillations have, I should do $\theta = \frac{150}{d_A}$, being $d_A$ the angular distance of the redshift at which we see it? $d_A=r/(1+z)$, being $r$ the distance.

Am I right there?

EDIT:
In view of the poor quality of that wikipedia section (mentioned by @ChrisWhite), I will rephrase the question independently of that section.

We know the BAO oscillations for the sound horizon happen at about $150\text{ Mpc}$. Given that, if I want to calculate the angle in the sky that covers, and if those oscillations are known to be given at a redshift $z$, then, which would be the proper way to calculate that angle?

I know it must be:

$$\theta \approx = \frac{d}{d_A}$$

Where $d_A$ is the angular distance, that can be calculated via $d_A=\frac{1}{1+z}\int_0^z \frac{dz'}{H(z')}$, begin $H(z')$ the inverse Hubble radio at that given redshift. My doubt is whether I should use $d=150Mpc$, or if I should multiply that with the scale factor $a$ to transform it into a physical distance.

Comment: Wow that's an awful wikipedia article. Just look at the formatting, the grammar, the unprofessional tone, not to mention the lack of capitalization of sentences. Probably better to delete the whole section than try to make sense of it.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I know, I was really surprised. I rephrased the question to make it independent of that wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

The BAOs became imprinted in the background density of the Universe at the time of [decoupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_%28cosmology%29), which happened at the same time as recombination, i.e. when the Universe was a factor $z \sim 1100$ smaller. At this time, they had a characteristing wavelength given by the speed of sound in the plasma at that time. This happened to be $\lambda_{\mathrm{BAO},\,z=1100} \sim 0.14 \,\mathrm{Mpc}$ *in physical length*, i.e. what you would measure if you were there. At this point, the waves got "frozen" in the gas so that it was compressed and rarefied on these scales, but as the Universe expanded, these compressions grew proportionally.

Now when we, *today*, measure the BAOs, we observe them at various redshifts and with correspondingly different wavelengths. But multiplying the physical length by $(1+z)$, where $z$ is the redshift at which we observe them, we can convert to *comoving* lengths so that the expansion is factored out, yielding the same result at all $z$, namely ~150 Mpc. Because by definition comoving and physical coordinates coincide today, this is the wavelength that the BAOs have today.

The angular diameter distance $d_\mathrm{A}$ is defined as the distance that relates the *physical*, not comoving, extend $D$ of an object and the angle $\theta$ covered on the sky by that object: $\theta = D/d_\mathrm{A}$.

For instance, the angle covered by a BAO at a redshift of, say, $z=2$ can be calculated in Python as:

```
from numpy import pi
from astropy.cosmology import Planck15        # Use a Planck 2016 cosmology
from astropy import units as u
z     = 2
dA    = Planck15.angular_diameter_distance(z) # Angular diameter distance
d_com = 150 * u.Mpc                           # Comoving size of the BAOs
d_phy = d_com / (1+z)                         # Physical size of BAO at z
theta = d_phy / dA * u.rad                    # Angle covered by BAO in radians
print('BAO size in degrees at z = '+str(z)+': ', theta.to(u.deg))
```

giving $1.6^\circ$ (at $z=2$).

Comment: The velocity of sound in the plasma approximated by $c_s=\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}}$.  If recombination occurred at 372,000 years, you get $r_s=c_s t=\frac{c}{\sqrt{3}}\times 1.17\times 10^{13}\space s$, or $r_s=0.066 Mpc$.  How did you get $0.14 Mpc$?

Comment: @DonaldAirey Calculating the size by assuming a wave traveling at $c_s$ for 372,000 yr can give an order-of-magnitude size, but this neglects the expansion of the Universe. I didn't calculate the size, though, I just took the observationally inferred value of $\sim100/h$ comoving Mpc.

Comment: I answered my own question above.  The distance sound moves up to 372,000 yr is 0.07 Mpc.  But that is just $\frac{1}{2}$ of the wavelength. The full wavelength is peak-to-trough-to-peak which would be $0.07\times 2 = 0.14\space Mpc$.

Comment: Why are you using the angular diameter distance to the SLS instead of the comoving distance?  We're not measuring the size of a galaxy, we're measuring the projections of the sound horizon onto a surface.  Seems to me like you're mixing apples and oranges here.

Comment: @DonaldAirey I'm not sure I understand. The angular diameter distance $d_\mathrm{A}$ to an object — e.g. a galaxy or a feature in the CMB — of physical size $D$ is the distance that fulfills the "standard" angle/distance law $\theta = D/d_\mathrm{A}$, so that should be appropriate, right?

Comment: I see the problem.  You're calculating physical lengths, while Planck is using co-moving lengths.  Planck quotes $r_*=144\space Mpc$ which isn't anywhere close to your value of $r_*=0.14 Mpc$.  However, and here's the really confusing part, they quote the Angular Diameter Distance as $D_A=13,000 Mpc$.  So it looked like you were mixing distance conventions, but I think it's the Planck study that's confusing things.  In one place they qualify the description with 'Co-moving Angular Diameter Distance' which strikes me as an oxymoron.

Comment: @DonaldAirey Rereading my 4 year old answer, I don't think it's too well-written, but  it seems I just aimed to answer the OP's desire to calculate the angle spanned by a BAO at a given z (2 in this example), from his/her knowledge of the BAO size today of 150 Mpc, which is also equal to the comoving size. The 0.14 Mpc I talk about is the _physical_ size at z=1100, ie when they were created. When you quote "13000 Mpc" as the ang. diam. dist., do you perhaps mean 13 Mpc (=13000 kpc)? This is namely the ang.diam.dist. to z=1100. Wrt. the "comoving ang.diam.dist." I agree, that doesn't make sense

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote.  Planck quotes $r_*=144\space Mpc$ (Sound Horizon) and $D_A=13,800\space Mpc$ (Angular Diameter Distance).  Divide $r_*$ by $D_A$ and you get roughly 1 degree.

Comment: @DonaldAirey Okay I understand now, but I think it's a bit convoluted way to do it. The BAO size today is $r_*$=144 Mpc, while at recombination it was a factor 1100 smaller,  i.e. 0.14 Mpc. The dA to z=1100 is 12.6 Mpc, so the angle spanned by a BAO at recombination is θ=0.14/12.6 rad = 0.6º. You get the same result if you use the $r_*$ today, and then define a "comoving angular diameter distance" by multiplying it by (1+z), i.e. 12.6 Mpc × 1100 = 13,900 Mpc.

Comment: At roughly 380,000 years, the sound waves could have moved only 0.07 Mpc. ($\frac {c}{\sqrt{3}})$.  However, with expansion, the sound traveled 144 Mpc.  Now this is the part where we seem to disagree, this distance is the distance of the sound wave from 0 to $z_{CMB}$.  At recombination, this distance was frozen and the temperature information was encoded in the photons.  Your description seems to indicate that the sound horizon continued to grow after $z_{CMB}$.

Comment: @DonaldAirey The sound horizon was frozen in comoving coordinates; in physical coordinates it continues to grow with the expansion of the Universe. I wrote "_As the Universe expanded, this wavelength grew proportionally_", and I agree this is somewhat ambiguous. I'll edit.

Comment: The baryons keep expanding with space, but the imprint of the Sound Horizon as seen in CMB is frozen at roughly $144 Mpc$.  That is, every integration I've seen for the CMB Sound Horizon is $\int_{z_{CMB}}^{\infty} dz$.  Let me know if I don't have this right.

Comment: @DonaldAirey Those 144 Mpc are in _comoving_ coordinates. Physical coords are a factor (1+z) smaller, so physically the imprint in the CMB — the actual size of the waves at that time — are only 0.14 Mpc. These waves were then frozen in the sense that they stopped moving _through_ space, but they did expand along with the Universe until today when they're a factor (1+z) larger, i.e. 144 Mpc in both physical and comoving coords.